# how do i change the behaviour of the cursor when im highlighting text on vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

when i highlight something without pressing `ctrl`, this happens: [image for better explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpCq3.png) (if i go from one line to the next, it doesn't highlight the entire first line, it just jumps to the next with a second cursor.)

but when i highlight something while pressing `ctrl`, the expected "normal" behavior occurs (it highlights the entire rest of the line and then goes to the next with the same cursor)

[example here, again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tN0O.png)

how can i *swap* these 2 behaviors? i must have effed something up in the settings but i can't find it and it's getting really annoying

Comment: [Selection > Column Selection Mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_column-selection-mode).

Comment: that worked, but i cant accept ur comment as an answer :'( thanks anyways!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

as @41686d6564 commented, selection>column selection mode did the trick. thanks!